# Using X-Send module to serve css, javascript and image files

Tags: php, css, fileserver, x-sendfile

I'm building a file server.  It is currently serving downloadable files (.doc, .zip) perfectly using X-Send.  It is possible to serve text based (css/javascript) or image files using x-send?  My understanding is this the most efficient method available but I am always open to ideas.

The code I currently have...(tried various versions with lines commented out/in)

```
//header('Content-Disposition: inline; filename="' . basename($cacheFile) . '"');
header('Content-Type: text/css');
//header('Expires: Sat, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT');
//header('Last-Modified: ' . gmdate( 'D, d M Y H:i:s' ) . ' GMT');
//header('Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate');
//header('Pragma: no-cache'); 
//header('Content-Length: ' .(string)(filesize("./cache/".$cacheFile)));
header('X-Sendfile: /path/to/site.css');
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have static files, it would probably better to serve the files directly to avoid the overhead of going through the backend (`php` in your case).

However, `mod_xsendfile` will serve whatever file you throw at it unmodified, so it doesn't matter if your stuff is some binary format (`.doc`, `.zip`) or text format (`.css`, `.js`).

Comment: Wow...thanks so much for answering. I'm using the file server to auto combine + mininify my css/js and do common image manipulation. I'm getting nothing using the code show above....any idea why?  A tar file worked perfectly.

Comment: I have no way of telling what is happening... You should have a look at the log (debug LogLevel debug)